# Расширение матрицы смежностей

Tags: математика, матрицы

Есть некоторое псевдо дерево квадрантов, которое изначально представляет из себя четыре прилежащих друг к другу областей:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слева представлена матрица смежностей этих четырех элементов. Для индексации используеться одно правило A - по часовой от верхнего левого угла.

Теперь, скажем, я хочу разбить область №2 на четыре части.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы обновить матрицу смежностей я должен заменить элемент №2 матрицей подобной изначальной, согласно установленному правилу A (зеленая зона).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собсвенно вопрос заключается есть ли операция или серия операция в математике матриц, которые позволили бы подставить вместо одного элемента другую матрицу смежностей и пересчитать связи между новыми и старыми элементами (красная зона)??

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае - никак. Просто потому, что одного описания зеленой матрицы недостаточно - надо еще описывать, как ее НОВЫЕ ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ (на которые она разбита) соотносятся со старыми.

Из зеленой матрицы никак не следует, что с 3 смежны 2.1 и 2.3, а не 2.2 и 2.4. Если вы замените в зеленой матрице 2.1 и 2.3, зеленая матрица не изменится, а вот красные поменяются. Так что ожной зеленой матрицы мало, и такая операция невозможна.

Comment: "Из зеленой матрицы никак не следует, что 3 смежны 2.1 и 2.3, а не 2.2 и 2.4". Почему нет? Области ведь индексируются по часовой стрелке от левого верхнего угла, значит все-таки знаем.

Comment: @eanmos Ну хорошо, поменяйте местами области 1 и 3. А если ВСЕ области исключительно нумеруются по часовой стрелке и делятся на 4 части по часовой же - то незачем прибегать к матрично-математическим делам, простой рекурсии будет достаточно. Но в любом случае проблемы начнутся позже - например, при делении области 1, в которой уже не будет "чистой" области 2, а будут только какие-то кусочки.

Comment: Мда. Думал все будет проще. Думал есть уже устоявшейся метод инкорпорирования одной матрицы в другую вместо элемента.

Answer (score 1):

Такая концепция есть: [иерархические матрицы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_matrix#:%7E:text=The%20most%20important%20innovation%20of,and%20solutions%20to%20matrix%20equations.) (с соответсвующим набором операций иерархической матричной арифметики). В данном представлении, матрица представляет собой в общем случае - дерево матриц, c данными хранящимися на листьях, при этом листья могут быть расположены на разных уровнях.

Однако концепция иерархических матриц обычно используется для гораздо более сложных задач, таких как представление интегральных и дифференциальных операторов в сжатой форме и т.д. Использование ее для матриц смежности - overkill.

Кроме того, [замечание Mikhailo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1157363/337980) имеет полную силу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

соседствование 3 с индивидуальными элементами 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 и 2.4 не определяется напрямую из структуры (в общем случае и с произвольными модификациями областей).

Поэтому, советую обратить внимание на более простые структуры данных и представление смежности. В зависимости от прикладной задачи, такие структуры как [k-d деревья](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) могут быть гораздо предпочтительнее.